# checking a bash command in a if statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I check the return value (true/false) of bash command in an if statement in Ruby. I want something like this to work,

```
if ("/usr/bin/fs wscell > /dev/null 2>&1")
                has_afs = "true"
        else
                has_afs = "false"
        end
```

It complains with the following error meaning, it will always return true.

```
 (irb):5: warning: string literal in condition
```

What's the correct syntax ?

UPDATE :

```
 /usr/bin/fs wscell
```

looks for `afs` installed and running condition. It will throw a string like this,

```
 This workstation belongs to cell <afs_server_name>
```

If `afs` is not running, the command exits with status 1

Comment: `if (\`/usr/bin/fs wscell > /dev/null 2>&\`)` ?

Comment: do you want to see if it had a return value of "0 versus -1" or if it outputs the text "true" from the command?

Comment: @NeilSlater, Your double accent marks don't work. Your edit works.

Comment: @iamauser: I didn't know how to escape backticks within backticks on SO. Now I do - just a backslash will do the trick :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want backticks rather than double-quotes. To check a program's output:

```
has_afs = `/usr/bin/fs wscell > /dev/null 2>&1` == SOMETHING ? 'true' : 'false'
```

Where SOMETHING is filled in with what you're looking for.

Comment: That's the correct syntax but note that this would only test the output of the command. I think he needs to check the exit status of the command, more details in my answer.

Comment: @gonz: Good point. Regardless of what the OP wanted to test, this was oversimplified just because I didn't know what it was.

Comment: @gonz : Isn't this syntax checking the exit status already ? So, will it be true even if the command fails ?

Comment: @iamauser: Well, it's ignoring the exit status. It's just giving you whatever the command output.

Comment: @iamauser: It's not checking the exit status code, backticks return the output of the executed command, if you put that inside an if condition it just coerces that string to bool. I'm just guessing that's not what you need since i'm not familiar with that command, usually the way to check this is through the exit status code, and I'm assuming here this command gives you a useful status code.

Comment: @Chuck: more info about the command could be useful, I can't say for sure exit status code will work for him but since he's redirecting all output to null dev this condition will always be true ("") so I'm pretty sure this won't work.

Comment: @Chuck: Just saw you added that SOMETHING cmp, that won't work either since `/usr/bin/fs wscell > /dev/null 2>&1` will always be ""

Comment: @gonz: I have updated my question with more info about the command.

Comment: @Chuck: I think in your code, `== SOMETHING` is not required for this case because the command inside the backticks will only provide either `true` or `false` because everything else is forwarded to `/dev/null` including the `stdout`.

Comment: @iamauser: It is, because the string `"false"` is truthy.

Comment: @Chuck: What you said it's true but it's not relevant, the backticks execution will always return "" since output is being redirected (not a boolean or a "boolean like" string) this is trivial to test for yourself on irb, no matter what's the value of SOMETHING the condition won't change depending on the command result which is the problem we're trying to solve. Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use system() or Backticks and **then check the exit status of the command ($?.exitstatus)**:

Heres a good quicktip read: http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands)

UPDATE:

```
system("/usr/bin/fs wscell > /dev/null 2>&1")  # Returns false if command failed
has_afs = $?.exitstatus != 1  # Check if afs is running
```

Comment: Do you have a more specific syntax to work with ? I will toggle my acceptance if you provide one. It seems I need to care about the exit status.

Comment: It will they express exactly the same thing but your way it's not considered idiomatic ruby code, it's redundant since != it's a boolean operator it will return true or false :)

Comment: @iamauser: Did the example help? Please ask if you need further explanation and remember to toggle your acceptance for future reference.

Comment: See my comment to Chuck's answer. As my command forwards everything to `/dev/null`, the answer Chuck gave (- SOMETHING) should work. So sticking to that as my acceptance, sorry.

Comment: @iamauser: I'm afraid it shouldn't. Since your command does that it will always return an empty string (output is being redirected) which will always evaluate to true no matter what string or status code the command returns. Test it yourself with something like `ls /bad/path > /dev/null 2>&1` status code will be 1, since the file doesn't exist but it will return "" and putting it inside an if condition will be evaluated as true, if you provide an existing path status code will be 0 (success) but the condition will still evaluate as true.